# Error Disk I/O in Quick Help Inspector Xcode9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

I have been using Xcode recently when I noticed that the Quick Help tab wasn't showing what is used to show, it was just displaying

```
Error
Domain=com.apple.DNTDocumentationSupport Code=0 "disk I/O error" UserInfo=
{NSLocalizedDescription=disk I/O error}
```

I looked up how to fix it, but I got no results.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Might want to run a disk check, the disk could _actually_ be failing, or there is some corrupt data present.

Comment: @MattClark I ran a disk check, it said the disk was fine

Comment: @MattClark Actually your answer helped me figure out the solution. I just had to restart my computer...

Comment: I have the same problem. Restarting the computer and xCode had no effect. Also did the latest update, no change.

Comment: Hmm…its working now after another restart of xCode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been facing this issue the past hour or so and the only fix I've found is to restart Xcode. Will report back if it comes back.